# Could not import view_production.views. Error was: No module named reportlab.graphics.shapes

Tags: django, django-views

First of all, I am not a django expert or even a web dev, I dont have any documentation for this app, and the guy that have made it, last time I saw it, was 4 years ago.

I am migrating one web app that contains django 0.97 with python 2.7 and wgsi 4.5.15, from a shared host to a new shared host.

On my new shared host, Apache is working, and while testing that webservice, I notice that for a login form, I was obtaining this error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /login/ajax/
Could not import view_production.views. Error was: No module named reportlab.graphics.shapes

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user1/apps/django/RMA/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  68. callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = resolver.resolve(request.path)
File "/home/user1/apps/django/RMA/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  163. sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/user1/apps/django/RMA/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  163. sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/user1/apps/django/RMA/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  119. return self.callback, args, kwargs
File "/home/user1/apps/django/RMA/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  128. raise ViewDoesNotExist, "Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e))

  ViewDoesNotExist at /login/ajax/
  Could not import view_production.views. Error was: No module named reportlab.graphics.shapes
```

I've already installed all python 2.7 dependencies that it were in previous host, but no changes.

On **/home/user1/apps/django/RMA/view_production/urls.py** I have this:

```
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import list_detail, simple

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^', include('RMA_Requests.urls')),
    (r'^view_production/deliveredproduct/(.+)/delete/$', 'view_production.views.delete_deliveredproduct'),
    (r'^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)/delete/$', 'django.contrib.admin.views.main.delete_stage'),
    (r'^view_production/job/add/$', 'view_production.views.add_job'),
    (r'^view_production/job/(.+)/$', 'view_production.views.change_job'),
    (r'^view_production/deliverie/list/(.+)/(.+)/$', 'view_production.manage_serials.list_serials'),
    (r'^view_production/deliverie/add/$', 'view_production.views.add_deliverie'),
    (r'^view_production/deliverie/(.+)/$', 'view_production.views.change_deliverie'),    
    (r'^view_production/deliveredproduct/add/$', 'view_production.views.deliveredproduct_wizard'),
    (r'^view_production/deliveredproduct/add1/$', 'view_production.views.deliveredproduct'),
    (r'^view_production/deliveredproduct/(.+)/$', 'view_production.views.deliveredproduct'),
    (r'^view_production/burnintest/add/$', 'view_production.views.add_burnin'),
    (r'^view_production/burnintest/(.+)/$', 'view_production.views.change_burnin'),
    (r'^view_production/repair/add/$', 'view_production.views.repair'),
    (r'^view_production/repair/(.+)/$', 'view_production.views.repair'),    
    (r'^report/(?P<rid>[^/]+)/$', 'view_production.views.report'),
    (r'^test/$', simple.direct_to_template, {'template': 'view_production/view_open_jobs.html'}),
    #(r'^charts/$',  'view_production.views.indexcharts'),
    (r'^ajaxteste/$',  'view_production.views.ajaxteste'),
    (r'^combochart/$',  'view_production.views.combochart'),
    (r'^charts/$',  'view_production.views.mainCharts'),
    (r'^charts/view/$',  'view_production.views.charts'),
    (r'^charts/image/$',  'view_production.views.imagecharts'),
    (r'^rpc/([^/]+)/$', 'view_production.views.rpc'),
    (r'^manageserials/$',  'view_production.views.manageserials'),
    (r'^login/ajax/$',  'view_production.views.loginajax'),
    (r'^remoteip','view_production.views.remoteip'),
    (r'^updates/viewconnector/$','view_production.views.updates_viewconnector'),
    
(r'^updates/viewconnector_page/$','view_production.views.updates_viewconnector_page'),
    (r'^', include('Repair.urls')), 
    
)
```

My question is, what do I need to setup in this new host for views to be able to function, like it was in previous host?

Note: All webapp content from previous host was migrated to this new host, databases inclueded.

Note 2: If you need more info just let me know, and I will updated this question,

Answer (score 1):

So it was a python 2.7 module that was missing, in this case, it was this version:

```
pip2.7 install --user reportlab=2.4
```